# Python (Numpy) array equal function is slow...is there a faster way?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a visual artist who is learning Python in order to create a specify set of artworks. In one, I'm coding Conway's classic Game of Life using a 2160x3840 grid.

However, the program is running slower than I'd hoped: It's been running on my three-year old iMac now for 24 hours and I only have two and a half "frames" processed. It will take weeks to make the run, and I have several runs to do.

I ran SnakeViz and 93% of my program's time is spent in a single function, where the primary activity is a series of comparisons. All of the "finch" colors and flashOfLifeColor are considered "live" cells in terms of Conway's rules.

```
def isLive (theColor):

    isCellLive = False
    finchColor_1 = numpy.array([247, 238, 214])
    finchColor_2 = numpy.array([202, 184, 88])
    finchColor_3 = numpy.array([103, 81, 68])
    flashOfLifeColor = numpy.array([249, 192, 0])

    if (numpy.array_equal(theColor, finchColor_1)) or
       (numpy.array_equal(theColor, finchColor_2)) or
       (numpy.array_equal(theColor,     finchColor_3)) or 
       (numpy.array_equal(theColor, flashOfLifeColor)):

        isCellLive = True

    return isCellLive
```

Is there a better (faster) way to write the if statement? Is there anything else I can do outside of optimization to speed things up?

Thanks,

--Darin

Edit:

Here is the function that is calling isLive to help understand what I am doing. I also want to mention again that I'm very new at Python programming, and do not yet know object programming at all, not any advanced techniques--thsu having a hard time deciphering some of the implementations of Conway's Rules that I am seeing on the web.

```
def countNeighborsNine(theArray, row, column):

    numberOfNeighbors = 0
    maxRow, maxColumn, depth = theArray.shape
    for rowModifier in range (-1,2):
        for columnModifier in range (-1, 2):

            rowNeighborPointer = (row + rowModifier) % maxRow
            columnNeighborPointer = (column + columnModifier) % maxColumn

            thePixel = theArray[rowNeighborPointer, columnNeighborPointer]

            if isLive(thePixel):
                numberOfNeighbors = numberOfNeighbors + 1

    return numberOfNeighbors
```

Comment: As soon as I posted this I see an obvious improvement--use the "dead" color instead of the live colors for the comparison. There are three dead colors--I still need significant improvement beyond that.

Comment: As far as I understood, you store the color of cell and then reconstruct is state from that color. Why you are doing that? Why not just store the state of the cell as some boolean or integer value and completely avoid this `isLive` function?

Comment: btw, you can try this implementations https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Python

Comment: I presume you have some large 2160x3840 `image`, and you want to get a list of all `live` cells? And is `theColor` is always a 3-element array?

Comment: Here is the larger context: I have a large array (2160x3840) with random "live' and "dead" cells. (Note the live and dead cells come in a variety of colors but are still just alive or dead--the color is just for looks.) I go to each cell and then look at each of the nine cells around it (eight plus itself) and look for live cells. When I find a live cell I count it. So this function, isLive, is the function I'm using on each of those nine cells to determine if I count it or not. Once all the cells around the base cell are counted I apply a rule from Conway, then go to the next cell...

Comment: The fact that you're calling this function, presumably in a giant loop, means that this is running in Python time rather than numpy. Function calls are expensive, array creation (which you do every single time the function is called) is expensive and it will add up. It might be helpful to show a small snippet of the larger array and the way you are applying this function. Then someone might be able to help vectorize it.

Comment: Updated the original post to shoe the function that is calling isLive. 73% of the program time is spent in countNeigborsNine, 93% in isLive. So the problem is certainly here. Hopefully I can avoid rewriting big parts of the code outside of these function! :)

Comment: Final disposition: Turns out there was something wrong with the install--my Macbook Pro (2011) was creating frames every half hour, many times faster than my much newer iMac (where the code was running). But learned a lot about numpy, vectorization, etc in the process. I did pull the isLive and countNeighborsNine code out of the separate functions and put them in the main loop, as implied by @roganjosh. Gained about 15% just from that.

Comment: The trick is really to try think in terms of vectorization though, which isn't always easy. In this case, it's possibly more "Pythonic" to keep things in functions for understanding (the gains might not balance against the reduced readability). Being able to put things into numpy arrays properly, however, brings _huge_ gains in speed. Also just to check, you define `finchColor_1 = numpy.array([247, 238, 214])` _before_ you enter the loop right? It's definitely more pythonic to define the constants only once, not each iteration of the following loop.

Comment: And an aside, if there are areas where you cannot avoid loops and still need high performance, you might be able to make use of [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/)

Comment: @roganjosh I'm trying to get my head around vectorization. Obviously worth learning. Until this thread I knew that numpy was "faster with arrays" than Python lists but I didn't realize that a big part of the reason was that Numpy was compiled code (duh), so now it's obvious that jumping in and out of an array isn't the most efficient thing. The next step I think is to learn more of the array functions so I can get a better handle on what is possible.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, readability is critical for me. I'm working on the code for an hour or two each weekday at a coffee shop so I need to be able to figure out what I did before with a minimum of fuss! :)  I do define the colors before the loop, but I don't do as VBB suggests (below) is use some sort of color ID system rather than doing all those (millions, hundreds of millions, really) of unnecessary companions of 3-element array vs 3-element array. I could do it more VBB's way with no loss in readability at all.

Comment: @roganjosh Never heard of numba but just spent some time reading about it. Seems fairly amazing and looks to be something that would be perfect for this project (and others I'm contemplating--all involve 4k video-sized arrays). Thanks for the heads up on that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution. Your image colours are probably in the range of `0..255` for R,G, and B each. I would first convert that into a single unique "colour ID " for the entire image (easy to process).

```
cid = grid_r * 256 * 256 + grid_g * 256 + grid_b
```

Do the same for your live/dead list:

```
def get_id(a):
     return a[0] * 256 * 256 + a[1] * 256 + a[2]
live_colours = np.array([get_id(finchColor_1), get_id(finchColor_2), get_id(finchColor_3), get_id(flashOfLifeColor)])
```

Now you can get all the 'live' cells in a single command:

```
alive = np.in1d(cid, live_colours).reshape(cid.shape)
```

Here, `alive` will be a 2160x3840 array of `True` and `False` elements. `np.in1d` takes each element in `cid` and returns `True` if it is in `live_colours`. The returned array is 1-d, so you need to reshape it to the same shape as your original image.

**Edit** - now to use this to count number of live neighbours for each cell. First I define a 2-d roll function.

```
def shifter(x, a, b):
   return np.roll(np.roll(x, a, axis=0), b, axis=1)
```

I take the `alive` array and pad it with "dead" cells on all 4 sides:

```
width = 2160
height = 3840
biglive = np.zeros((width + 2, height + 2))
biglive[1:-1, 1:-1] = alive.astype(int)
live_count = shifter(biglive, -1, -1) + shifter(biglive, -1, 0) + shifter(biglive, -1, 1) + shifter(biglive, 0, -1) + shifter(biglive, 0, 1) + shifter(biglive, 1, -1) + shifter(biglive, 1, 0) + shifter(biglive, 1, 1)
```

We ignore the padded zero cells at the end.

```
live_count = live_count[1:-1, 1:-1]
```

This is a 2160x3840 grid, where each cell contains the number of live neighbours. I generated a random image, and the entire process took a couple of seconds to calculate the number of alive neighbours for the complete 2160x3840 set.

Comment: Hi VBB,  Thanks for the detailed answer. I semi-get where you are coming from reading through the code--tomorrow when I'm more clear-headed(!) I'll put it into the interpreter so I can really understand what is happening and why. Thanks again. Your code seem so much more compact than mine! :)

Comment: Nice solution. One quibble: the OP's neighbour code actually does wrap around, so you can do away with the padding. Also, but you'd have to check whether that's intentional, they seem to count the centre pixel as a neighbour.

Comment: Thanks @PaulPanzer. I assumed the no-wrap and 8-neighbours-only as per usual game of life rules.

Comment: @VBB I won't be able to get back to this until later today. But I will check in and report success (or express further bewilderment). :) Thanks for all the excellent advice from you and all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Just some advise to find by yourself the best way.

- Begin with a pure python project, then a numpy one.
- Separate the game logic and  visualization.

  For exemple one array to distinguish alive/dead, an other to count neighbors.
  Use imshow(neighbours, cmap=my_conway_map) for visualization.
- Never use for loops on numpy arrays, it's slow.

A minimal exemple :

```
world=randint(0,2,(5,5))
mask=ones((3,3))
mask[1,1]=0
neighb=scipy.signal.convolve2d(world,mask,'same')
subplot(121)
a=imshow(world,interpolation='none',cmap=cm.Greys)
subplot(122) 
colorbar()
b=imshow(neighb,interpolation='none')
show()
```

[image: conway]